Sampling from a 2D meshgrid which has been column_stack'ed/train_test_split sampling
Pardon my Python ignorance, but
np.meshgrid, np.column_stack and train_test_split has me confused a bit.
In short: I made a 2D meshgrid which I then have column_stack'ed. This represents the domain of a function I'm predicting. Later I wish to randomly sample some points from the domain and get the corresponding function predictions.
As far as I understand, the domain now contains all combinations of (x,y) coordinates, so I should have no problem randomly sampling points x_s and y_s from each axis , combine them to a coordinate (x_s, y_s) and get the corresponding function prediction. However, serval of the sampled points aren't in the domain. (it's important that the y_s and x_s are sampled independently)
So, I have a set of coordinates forming a plane on which I work with a function. Say for example the grid is 20x20, I define the grid as so:
x = np.sort(np.random.normal(0, 1, size = 20))
y = np.sort(np.random.normal(0, 1, size = 20))

I make my 2D meshgrid
input_X, input_Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

For later use, I column_stack the domain like so:
domain = np.column_stack((input_X.reshape(-1), input_Y.reshape(-1)))

I then separate my data for training and testing as such:
X_train, X_test, f_train, f_test = train_test_split(domain, f_evals, test_size = 0.80)

My problem comes when I want to randomly sample coordinates from the x-axis and then the y-axis, like so:
x_samples = np.random.choice(X_test[:,0], size = number_of_samples, replace=False)

y_samples = np.random.choice(X_test[:,1], size = number_of_samples, replace=True)

Then for any pair of (x_s, y_s) I want to get the associated predicted function value.
So for each sampled coordinate (x_s, y_s) I want the corresponding row-index in X_test, and then get the predicted function value at the same row-index from a list of predictions (predictions are made on all points coordinates in X_test).
However, serval of my sampled coordinates doesn't exist in the X_test??
I've made a slight workaround, choosing only 'valid' points, but I'm not quite satisfied with this solution and I wish to understand the problem(s) with my approach above.
I (mis?)understood that after meshgrid(x, y) -> column_stack(x, y), my domain should contain all combinations of (x, y) coordinates. So how can I then generate coordinates that doesn't exist in the domain, by randomly sampling from the axes from each axis.
Does the problem stem from how I construct the domain or from  train_test_split(...)  ?
Result vs. expectation. I randomly sampled points from x_s \subset X_test[:,0]  and y_s \subset X_test[:,1], combined the samples into a list of coordinates (x_s, y_s) which I expected to find in my test domain X_test, but many sampled coordinates didn't exist in X_test.
